# Unexpected end of input: ApolloClient error in getting response from AWS API Gateway

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, angular, graphql, apollo

I am using Apollo within my Angualar App and I am now hitting this issue. I have a GraphQL endpoint on a AWS Lambda and through the API Gateway I am seeing the response come back correctly but when it goes through reading it it throws this error. AWS is using LAMBDA_PROXY

```
//setup
const client = new ApolloClient({
  networkInterface: createNetworkInterface({
    opts: {
      mode: 'no-cors',
    },
    uri: "https://xxxxxxx.execute-api.ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/dev/graphql"
  }),
});

//make the call
this.apollo.watchQuery({
        forceFetch: true,
        query: QueryToSend
    }).subscribe(({data}) => {
        ...process...

    }, error => {
        console.log(error);
    });

//the error...
Network error: Unexpected end of input
    at new ApolloError (ApolloError.js:31)
    at QueryManager.js:128
    at t.invoke (polyfills.js:3)
    at Object.onInvoke (ng_zone.js:236)
    at t.invoke (polyfills.js:3)
    at e.run (polyfills.js:3)
    at polyfills.js:3
    at t.invokeTask (polyfills.js:3)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (ng_zone.js:227)
    at t.invokeTask (polyfills.js:3)
```

The request is

```
const QueryToSend= gql`
    query data { 
        getSuperDefinitionList{
            id,
            name, 
        }
    }
`;
```

Not sure what is wrong. I invoke from Postman and SoapUI the same request body works. I even see that fiddler response has the correct response...

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: ...
Connection: keep-alive
Date: Fri, 13 Jan 2017 21:10:10 GMT
x-amzn-RequestId: ab0fghjghja-d9d4-11e6-b19a-090dsfvdgcebe
X-Amzn-Trace-Id: Root=1-58794232-c7f7157d28e033330dbbe6f2
X-Cache: Miss from cloudfront
Via: 1.1 a1d4b598e9b2fghjgfhj3991961a666a6.cloudfront.net (CloudFront)
X-Amz-Cf-Id: XHeOfghjfghjUthDPKxVbCrFoLM4iOYpf9X9mWlu2Z374grmuAv5jMjg==

{"data":{"getSuperDefinitionList":[{"id":"83d3b09f-a947-4a33-bcb0-f5c9e0446ace","name":"S","__typename":"SuperDefinitionType"}]}}
```

All looks ok from AWS but Apollo or some javascript library it uses does not.

What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

After writing this I had a hunch.

I removed

```
opts: {
  mode: 'no-cors',
},
```

And made sure I returned the correct headers (the last 3 were omitted):

```
        var response = new APIGatewayProxyResponse
        {
            StatusCode = result.Result.IsError ? (int)HttpStatusCode.BadRequest : (int)HttpStatusCode.OK,
            Body = result.Result.Body,
            Headers = new Dictionary<string, string> {
                { "Content-Type", "application/json" },
                { "Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*" },
                { "Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET,POST,OPTIONS" },
                { "Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Connection, Host, Origin, Referer, Access-Control-Request-Method, Access-Control-Request-Headers, User-Agent, Accept, Content-Type, Authorization, Content-Length, X-Requested-With, Accept-Encoding, Accept-Language" },
             }
        };
```